# Extract url from character strings

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of characters

[image]

I was wondering how to extract just the urls in each character string. I've tried the following, which kinda works, but is not perfect.

```
sub(".*http", "", character_string)
```

Ideally, I would like to extract out the url and nothing more or less.

Comment: Actually, I think you have a png image not a vector of characters.  One thing I also want to learn how to do is to convert an image, as you show, into text that I can apply regular expression to.

Comment: Please paste as plain text.

Comment: @HarlanNelson Assuming that you have a vector of characters in R called `strings`   you can use `dput(strings)` to get a nice text representation suitable for adding to a question like this. If the vector is too long to include,  consider `dput(strings, 20)`

Comment: @G5W I think Harlan meant it as a joke...

Comment: @zx8754 and I was about to recommend an OCR... :) JasonBail, you could try `gsub`. It matches the expression more than one times. `sub` matches it only one (first) time.

Comment: @zx8754 You are right. Thanks.

Comment: fwiw, [tesseract](https://github.com/ropensci/tesseract) does an ok to mediocre job: `library(tesseract); ocr('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PxKW.png')`